# Отключить создание пользовательских сессий в Yii 1.x для некоторых запросов к сайту?

Tags: php, yii, cookie, сессия, request

Мобильное приложение делает Ajax-запросы к сайту на **Yii 1.x.** В Yii для каждого такого запроса стартует новая пользовательская сессия, потому что мобильное приложение не умеет хранить COOKIE для передачи PHPSESSID сайту.

Как сделать так, чтобы при запросах из мобильного приложения сессии в Yii не стартовали? При этом как определить именно запросы от мобильного приложения я знаю. **Вопрос именно про остановку механизма сессий!**

Кстати сессии хранятся в БД, конфигурация такая:

```
'session' => array(
    'timeout' => 32400, // 9 часов
    'class' => 'system.web.CDbHttpSession',
    'connectionID' => 'db',
    'sessionTableName' => 'session',
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Переопределить класс, и выключить [автостарт](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#autoStart-detail) сессии при неком условии:

```
class DbHttpSession extends CDbHttpSession{

    public function init()
    {
        if($this->isMobile()){
            $this->autoStart = false;
        }
        parent::init();
    }

    public function isMobile(){
        //...
        return true;
    }

    //...
}
```

Указать свой класс в файле конфигурации:

```
'session' => array(
    'class' => 'application.components.DbHttpSession',
    //...
),
```

Comment: Сделал всё как вы написали, не сработало! Сессия создается..

Comment: Причем, сделал в CHttpSession в public function init() такую штуку:         var_dump($this->autoStart); - выдает false, т.е. по логике вещей всё должно было сработать как вы писали, анн нет..

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы - переопределить метод init() класса CWebUser:

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser 
{

    public function init()
    {
        if ($this->isMobile()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            parent::init();
        }
    }
```